# Is having RefCursor as an OUT parameter of a Postgresql function, allowed?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plsql, stored-functions, ref-cursor

I know the following is possible. i.e I can have a ref cursor as a return value in Postgresql.

```
CREATE FUNCTION employeefunc(int) RETURNS refcursor AS '
DECLARE ref refcursor;  
BEGIN
OPEN ref FOR SELECT * FROM employee where id = $1;
RETURN ref;
END;
```

But can we have a ref cursor as an OUT parameter in a postgresql function?

For your reference, following the the Oracle equivalent of what I'm looking for.

```
create or replace procedure employeefunc(rc out sys_refcursor) as
begin
open rc for 'select * from employee';
end;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `CREATE PROCEDURE` in Postgresql like Oracle PL/SQL. You may create a `FUNCTION` with `OUT` parameter as `REFCURSOR`, but the `RETURN TYPE` should be specified as `REFCURSOR`.

```
CREATE FUNCTION employeefunc (rc_out OUT refcursor)
RETURNS refcursor
AS
$$
BEGIN
    OPEN rc_out
    FOR
    SELECT *
    FROM employees;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

As you could see, there is no `RETURN` statement. That's because if the function has `OUT` variables, you can't end the function using a `RETURN` statement with a *value*, but using a simple `RETURN;` is valid.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I have another question. Say I'm calling this procedure through java. In order to obtain a ref cursor returned as an OUT param or with a RETURN statement, in both cases we'll have to register an out parameter (statment.registerOutParameter). Is the above statement correct?

Comment: @Snitch : You are welcome. As for your question, Java is not my area. You may google  it or ask that as a separate question.

Comment: Cool, thanks again Kaushik! I would have upvoted too if I had permission! You saved a lot of my time!

Answer (score 0):

Postgresql stored procedures does not support **OUT** parameters like other Servers do. But it supports **INOUT** parameters which we can use to perform output tasks.

Note: Stored procedures in Postgresql are introduced in **Version 11**; So, if you are using an earlier version, please upgrade it before using stored procedures.

Thank you !!